# Responsive 'grid'?

Tags: html, grid, zurb-foundation

I have the unenviable task of 'retrofitting' a website to be responsive, and have been given the Zurb foundation 980px grid. I'm a bit lost as to how I'm supposed to fit my existing site to this - do I have to redesign it completely to align elements with the new grid?? I understand that the site will proportionally scale and at certain breakpoints will hide some elements and load new css for others - but it's the grid thing I don't get?

Comment: Was the legacy site built with a grid framework like 960gs?

Comment: Is 960 pixels just the width of the site, or did it use a grid framework too?

Comment: Well the original design is to a 960 grid, but the zurb 'grid's 980px. But the grid is pretty loose - (gutters between columns of 43px..) so I'm really not sure what use it is.. thanks for your assistance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've converted two 960gs websites so far and both went pretty quick.

**For starters, make sure you have referenced all of the foundation resources in your project (Javascripts and CSS).**

First things first, you mentioned that your grid is 960 but zurb's is 980. We'll it's totally custom. What you need to do is add a CSS override. To do this open the app.css and add the following code:

> .row {
>       max-width: 960px; }

Next, you'll need to look at your current HTML and see how similar it is to Zurb's. In 960gs, there are no rows, only columns. So in my project I needed to add the rows, and do a find and replace on the column classes, like so:

Before:

```
<div class="container_12">
  <div class="grid_8">
          ...    
  </div>
  <div class="grid_4">
          ...
  </div>
</div>
```

After:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="eight columns">
          ...    
  </div>
  <div class="four columns">
          ...
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

You'll need to do this on all of your pages. **Remember each <row> must contain only 12 columns no more no less.**

Once you have this done, you should be well on your way. You'll probably have some additional work cut out for you since you are now dealing with a flexible grid and flexible content.

Comment: Thanks Ed - very helpful.. your time and input is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Adapt.js plugin found on the 960.gs website.

http://adapt.960.gs/

It is already compatible with 960gs so you don't need to change anything in the framework.

However, you may still need to re-code some internal CSS classes to adapt to fluidity.